# recombine two chromosomes in matlab

Tags: matlab, matrix, genetic-algorithm

I want to recombine (crossover) two chromosomes (genetic algorithm).
This is my pseudocode, where is my problem ?

**popu** is 50 * 10 matrix.(my population)
**popsize** =50
**selected** is 1*50 matrix ( selected best individuals with fitness evaluator )

```
function pop = recombin( popu,selected )
    global popsize;
    pop=zeros(50,10);
    for i=1:popsize/2
        rc=randi([1,10]);
        for j=1:10
            if(j<=rc)
                pop(i,j)=popu(selected(i),j);
                pop(i+25,j)=popu(selected(i+25),j);
            else
                pop(i,j)=popu(selected(i+25),j);
                pop(i+25,j)=popu(selected(i),j);
            end
            %keyboard
        end
    end
end
```

My code works correctly (syntactically) . But I am not sure this is correct way to combine 2 chromesomes in a generic algorithm :(

Comment: I'm having trouble understanding the problem you're experiencing. Does the code run but produce unexpected results, or are you having trouble making the code run without errors? Can you edit your question and add some details to explain that?

Comment: @EitanT tnx for you attention

Comment: You might get some better performance if you eliminate the for loop and say something like pop(i,1:rc-1) = popu(selected(i+25),1:rc-1); pop(i,rc:end)=popu(selected(i),rc:end);.

Comment: @Bill tnx, yes good lead, do you see any problem in my code? is it ok?

Answer (score 0):

The short answer to your question is: the code is (almost) correct, it performs a single-point crossover.

The code is almost correct in the sense that the first element of each individual is never swapped: since rc is in [1, 10] and the swap is when `j` is strictly larger than rc, this means `pop(i, 1)` is always assigned to `popu(selected(i), 1)` (and not `popu(selected(i + 25), j)`).

This could a desired feature but rather looks like an undesired border effect. It could be prevented by using this line instead: `rc = randi([0,10]);`.

So considering Bill's comment, the code would look like this:

```
function pop = recombin(popu, selected)
    [popsize, dimension] = size(popu);
    pop = zeros(popsize, dimension);
    halfpopsize = floor(popsize / 2)

    for i = 1:halfpopsize
        rc = randi([0, 10]);
        pop(i, :) = [popu(selected(i), 1:rc), popu(selected(i + halfpopsize), rc + 1:end)];
        pop(i + halfpopsize, :) = [popu(selected(i + halfpopsize), 1:rc), popu(selected(i), rc + 1:end)];
    end
end
```